# jquery - XML Parsing Error: no element found Location

Tags: jquery, xml

When using ajax call in the same domain (localhost), I always got the XML Parsing Error: no element found Location.

The start + end is Date object. I am using FullCalendar jquery plugin (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'events',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {title: title, start: start, end: end}
});
```

Thank you for your effort!!

Comment: Are you expecting XML? If so, the dataType is wrong

Comment: No, I am not expecting XML

Comment: you need to more specific about error, it could be on server side??

Comment: I am using Snap (Haskell) in server side. Simply need to post JSON data to server to add it into db. I have no idea what I need to specific